# What IR Codes are the Power Function remotes sending to the receiver?

Tags: power-functions, remote-control

The PF [IR Speed Remote Control](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8879-1) (the train one) is "7 speeds" but as I turn the dial to make it go faster it's hard to tell what speed it's at. I wonder if I could setup my programmable remote so that pressing 1 puts the train at speed one, 2 at two and so on. Is there a reference for this somewhere?

Comment: Which train motor is it?

Comment: Some programmable remotes are also learning remotes, so you could just put the remote in learning mode and point the train remote at it.

Answer (score 8):

As with most things related to Power Function,s you can find this information on [Philo's page on Power Functions](http://www.philohome.com/pf/pf.htm).

If you scroll down a little, you'll find a link to "[LEGO Power Functions RC](http://www.philohome.com/pf/LEGO_Power_Functions_RC_v120.pdf)" which is a document straight from LEGO outlining the PF RC protocol. The protocol does include commands to set an absolute speed.

Now, whether you can make sense of it is another story altogether. That's what [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com/) used to create the [NXT IRLink Sensor](http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NIL1046), and with it connected to a NXT you can indeed send the commands to set the speed to a defined level instead of increasing/decreasing.

Note that due to power limitations in the NXT, IRLink has a short transmission range.